# Ubuntu Server installed on USB Stick, not recognized after restart

Tags: boot, server, 16.04, usb, hard-drive

Hello I have an old Laptop without a HDD. So I formatted a USB Stick to FAT32 and installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on it. All worked great, I installed some applications but after a reboot (not the first, but the second or third) my laptop says there is no Drive plugged in. I installed it 2 times again but everytime the same problem. Has somebody an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
For everyone with the same Problem:
activate network boot in the bios

Comment: Can you mark this as solved by pressing the little check next to this answer?